# Generating an unique Sudoku

Tags: java, unique, sudoku

I am making a Sudoku game in Java and I need some help.

I've got two classes for generating the Sudoku puzzle: `SudokuSolver,` SudokuGenerator`.

The `SudokuSolver` creates a full valid Sudoku puzzle for an empty table and the `SudokuGenerator` removes a random value from the table and then checks (using `SudokuSolver`) if the Sudoku puzzle is *unique*.

I found out that the Sudoku puzzle isn't unique, so I think my algorithm for checking the uniqueness of the Sudoku puzzle is bad.

For example, I have this Sudoku puzzle

```
497816532
132000000
000000000
910600080
086009000
000084963
021063059
743050020
600278304
```

And this solution:

```
497816532
132**745**698
568392471
914**637**285
386529147
275184963
821463759
743951826
659278314
```

I went to https://www.sudoku-solutions.com/ and I added the pattern of my Sudoku and they gave me another solution:

```
497816532
132**547**698
568392471
914**635**287
386729145
275184963
821463759
743951826
659278314
```

The funny think is that they're saying that *This puzzle is valid and has a unique solution.*

Some opinions?

**SudokuSolver**

```
public class SudokuSolver {
    
    public static final int GRID_SIZE = 9;
    public static final int SUBGRID_SIZE = 3;
    private static int validRow = 0;
    private static int validCol = 0;
    
    private int[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    public boolean solveSudoku(int[][] values, int forbiddenNum) {
        
        if(!findUnassignedLocation(values)) return true;
        
        //suffle the nums array - for having a different valid sudoku
        shuffleNums();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
            
            int num = nums[i];
            
            if(num == forbiddenNum) continue; //
            
            if(isSafe(values,validRow, validCol, num)) {
                values[validRow][validCol] = num;
                
                if(solveSudoku(values, forbiddenNum)) return true;
                            
                if(validCol == 0) {
                    validRow--;
                    validCol = 8;
                }else{
                    validCol--;
                }
                
                values[validRow][validCol] = 0;
            }
            
        }

        
        return false;
        
    }
    
    public boolean createValidSudoku(int[][] values) {
        
        if(!findUnassignedLocation(values)) return true;
        
        shuffleNums();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
            
            int num = nums[i];
            
            if(isSafe(values,validRow, validCol, num)) {
                values[validRow][validCol] = num;
                
                if(createValidSudoku(values)) return true;
                            
                if(validCol == 0) {
                    validRow--;
                    validCol = 8;
                }else{
                    validCol--;
                }
                
                values[validRow][validCol] = 0;
            }
            
        }

        
        return false;
    }

    private void shuffleNums() {
    
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i = nums.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
            
            int a = nums[index];
            nums[index] = nums[i];
            nums[i] = a;
        } 
        
}
    
    private boolean findUnassignedLocation(int[][] values) {
        for(int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE; col++) {
                if (values[row][col] == 0) {
                    validRow = row;
                    validCol = col;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    private boolean usedInRow(int[][] values, int row, int num) {
        for (int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE; col++) {
            if(values[row][col] == num) return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    private boolean usedInCol(int[][] values, int col, int num) {
        for (int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE; row++) {
            if(values[row][col] == num) return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    private boolean usedInBox(int[][] values, int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int num) {
        for(int row = 0; row < SUBGRID_SIZE; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < SUBGRID_SIZE; col++) {
                if (values[row + boxStartRow][col + boxStartCol] == num) return true;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    private boolean isSafe(int[][] values,int row, int col, int num) {
        return !usedInRow(values, row, num) &&
               !usedInCol(values, col, num) &&
               !usedInBox(values, row - row % 3, col - col % 3, num);
    }
    
    public void printGrid(int[][] values) {
        for (int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE; col++) {
                System.out.print(values[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**SudokuGenerator**

```
public class SudokuGenerator {
    
    private int[][] generatorValues = new int[9][9];

    
    public void generateSudoku() {
        SudokuSolver sudokuSolver = new SudokuSolver();
        //generate a random valid sudoku for an empty table
        sudokuSolver.createValidSudoku(generatorValues);
        
        int count = 0;
        printNums(generatorValues);
        
        while(count < 40){
            Random random = new Random();
            
            int row = 0;
            int col = 0;

            if(count < 15){
                row = random.nextInt(3);
                col = random.nextInt(9);    
            } else if (count >= 15 && count < 30) {
                row = random.nextInt(3) + 3;
                col = random.nextInt(9);    
            }else {
                row = random.nextInt(3) + 6;
                col = random.nextInt(9);    
            }

            
            int num = generatorValues[row][col];
            int tempValues[][] = Arrays.copyOf(generatorValues, generatorValues.length);
            
            //System.out.println("Row:" + row + "Col: " + col + "Num: " + num);
            
            //Set the cell to 0;
            if(generatorValues[row][col] != 0){
                generatorValues[row][col] = 0;
            } else{
                continue;
            }

            //If found a solution, set cell back to original num
            if(sudokuSolver.solveSudoku(tempValues, num)) {
                generatorValues[row][col] = num;
                continue;
            }
            
            count++;
            
        }   
        System.out.println("------------------");
        printNums(generatorValues);


    }
    
    private void printNums(int[][] values) {
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                System.out.print(values[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    public int[][] getGeneratorValues () {
        return generatorValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @JoeC Thank you. I will debug my code and if the problem persists I will rewrite my problem in another. I think I should delete my post, right?